# Using PhpSpreadsheet at OpenCart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, opencart2.3

I have OpenCart 2.3.0.2 installed on localhost, I want to use PhpSpreadsheet library for my OpenCart project. Does anyone here have used them? I confuse on how to call the library. I want to upload Excel data for a product. This Excel data will be uploaded to folder and insert all data on that sheet to my database.

I have uploaded Spreadsheet folder to system/library, tried to call the function, it always failed.

Comment: Could you please post the error message with which it fails?

Comment: Call to undefined function it said... I will do some tricky code right now... Hope it will works...

Comment: Any luck on this ?

Comment: It's a little bit tricky @DhirajBastwade in the end, I include my php files to model. I put my php file in root folder, and code function at there... just like that and it works...

Comment: I did this by doing require_once in my controller. Working like charm.